# Return NULL instead of composite value from PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql

Let us have the following things in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TYPE struct AS (x INT, y INT);
CREATE TABLE tbl (a INT, b struct);

CREATE FUNCTION find_tbl_entry(clear BOOL) RETURNS tbl AS $$
DECLARE k tbl;
BEGIN
  IF clear THEN
    k.b := NULL;
  END IF;

  RETURN k;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

That is, we have a function returning a value of the composite type `tbl`, which in turn has an attribute `b` of composite type `struct` as one of its attributes. (The original problem is more interesting - a translating function returning a row with some attributes translated accordingly; the problem boils down to the presented code, though.)

`SELECT find_tbl_entry(FALSE)` results in `(,(,))`, i.e., NULL as the value of `a` and an empty struct (pair of NULL and NULL) as the value of `b`, which is somewhat expected.

Now, even `SELECT find_tbl_entry(TRUE)` results in `(,(,))`, i.e., even if the `b` attribute is explicitly set to `NULL`, the result is not `NULL`, but it is still the empty struct.

What can I do for the function `find_tbl_entry` to return `NULL` in the `b` attribute?

---

**EDIT:** As it turns out, the strange thing is the assignment `k.b := NULL`. When extending the function:

```
k.b := NULL;
RAISE NOTICE '%', k.b IS DISTINCT FROM NULL;
```

it emits "NOTICE:  t". Thus, it seems assigning `NULL` to a composite value actually assigns a composite having all attributes `NULL`. Which is quite strange, considering the fact that `NULL` values are distinguishable from `(NULL,NULL)` when stored in a table (`UPDATE tbl SET b = NULL` results in `b IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL` holding for each row; on the other hand, `UPDATE tbl SET b = (NULL,NULL)` is `false` for that test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to either:

Return the `null` directly in instead of returning the assigned variable:

```
create or replace function find_tbl_entry()
returns tbl as $$
declare s struct;
begin
    s := null;
    return (1, nullif(s, (null,null)::struct));
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select a, b, b is null from find_tbl_entry();
 a | b | ?column? 
---+---+----------
 1 |   | t
```

Or compare at function usage time:

```
select coalesce(nullif((find_tbl_entry()).b, (null,null)::struct), (1,2)::struct);
 coalesce 
----------
 (1,2)
```

Comment: Do you happen to know of a variant of the first option which would be defensive against modifications of `tbl` columns? I mean, when an extra column is added to `tbl`, it would be nice for the function not to break - especially when the problem only appears at run time, when the function actually gets called.

Comment: @OndřejBouda Edited

Comment: Thanks for editing, the code does not seem to be correct, though (`RETURN` should have no parameter in a function returning a table), and speaking of types, it returns a table rather than a single row.
I actually get the point, however. Simply defining the return type as a new composite type `t` and returning it, using the proposed construct `return (1, nullif(s, (null,null)::struct));` resolves the problem. Could you fix the edited version, please, so that I could accept the answer?

Comment: @OndřejBouda Fixing the `returns table` version gives the same problem back. So you are out of options.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, a composite value (the SQL standard call this a “value of degree > 1”) is `NULL` when all its components are `NULL`, so PostgreSQL is behaving correctly.

ISO/IEC 9075-2:2003, chapter 8, verse 7, sayeth:

> **8.7 <null predicate>**
>
> **Function**
>
> Specify a test for a null value.
>
> **Format**
>
> ```
> <null predicate> ::= <row value predicand> <null predicate part 2>
> <null predicate part 2> ::= IS [ NOT ] NULL
> ```
>
> **Syntax Rules**
>
> None.
>
> **Access Rules**
>
> None.
>
> **General Rules**
>
> 1) Let *R* be the value of the <row value predicand>.
>
> 2) Case:
>
> a) If *R* is the null value, then “`R IS NULL`” is *True*.
>
> b) Otherwise:
>
> i) The value of “`R IS NULL`” is
>
> Case:
>
> 1) If the value of every field in *R* is the null value, then *True*.
>
> 2) Otherwise, *False*.
>
> ii) The value of “`R IS NOT NULL`” is
>
> Case:
>
> 1) If the value of no field in *R* is the null value, then *True*.
>
> 2) Otherwise, *False*.

(If you think that this is crazy, you are not alone.)

You can verify that PostgreSQL handles such a value correctly:

```
SELECT (ROW(NULL,ROW(NULL,NULL))::tbl).b IS NULL;
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

I understand that you would rather like the value to read `(NULL, NULL)`, but you cannot get that with PostgreSQL. I hope it is a comfort to you that it will nonetheless behave correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it does not quite solve the exact question. I have already played with it, finding out that `(NULL,NULL) IS NULL` returns `true`. No doubt Postgres behaves correctly, either.
Originally, I used `COALESCE((find_tbl_entry(...)).b, X)`, where I wanted `X` to be returned if the `b` attribute was `NULL`. Unexpectedly, it kept returning `(NULL,NULL)` instead of `X`, which is because `COALESCE` apparently uses `IS DISTINCT FROM NULL` for testing which value to return.
I want to write a function safe for `COALESCE`, which will be when `b` is returned as `NULL`.

Comment: ...and, despite the practical issues, I was also curious about the case when I assign `NULL` to the `b` field and still get `(NULL,NULL)` in the returned value. Which really seems strange, despite the definition of the `IS NULL` operator.

Comment: Yes, it is a mess. There have been discussions how to improve it, but no good direction forward has been found.